# WP Multisite - domain mapping to domain.com and separate site to domain.com/help

Tags: multisite, subdomains, domain, domain-mapping, network-admin

I'm considering setting up a WP multisite network. It would seem to fit my situation perfectly. There's one thing I still need to find out about domain mapping.

Say I have the multisite installed on the following example root domain: `multisiteroot.com`. Each subsite is installed on a subdomain. Further, I also registered a domain: `businessdomain.com`.

I now want to have two separate WP websites and map them to respectively `businessdomain.com` and `businessdomain.com/help` (or sth like that).

Is it possible to install WP Multisite on a root domain with subsites on subdomains, and map two of those subsites to `businessdomain.com` and `businessdomain.com/help`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible (see https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/). For sub-domains you'll need to confirm that your DNS has a wildcard entry for your domain. So, based on your root domain, this would work for: mysub1.multisiteroot.com, mysub2.multisiteroot.com, etc.

If you wanted to us different domain names for subsites, then you'd need to have those domain names point to your IP, and then, in the Network Admin "Edit Site" page for your new subsite (Network Admin path: All Sites > Edit (site site to be modified):

1. Info tab - Change "Site Address (URL)" to the URL to name of your subsite (e.g. "https://businessdomain.com"), then click "Save Changes";
2. "Settings" tab - change the "Siteurl" and "Home" values to the URL for your subsite, then click "Save Changes".

As for "businessdomain.com/help", this is a subfolder. I recommend using a subdomin "help.businessdomain.com", using the website I listed above and mu notes.

I hope I didn't miss a step, or two.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Deronimo, thanks for your help! I didn’t test it yet, but it looks great so I marked it as correct. Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: Curious that the documentation only mentions [Site Address (URL)](https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-multisite-domain-mapping/#update-wordpress). If we change only that, the frontend is mapped and the backend is not.